# How to fix: How to show state with onClick to div?(React)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have sidebar with document types on it(docs, table, slider, html ..). I want that, if i click on docs  element it will show docs in another div like a header.

I have 3 files: DocumentType.tsx, Sidebar.tsx and Results.tsx

In DocumentType.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';

const documentType = (props ) =>{
     return(
        <div>
          <p id="fileType">{props.type}</p>
        </div>
     )
};

export default documentType;
```

In Sidebar.tsx:

```
          typeState = {
        documentTypes: [
          { type: "Dokumendid" },
          { type: "PDF" },

        ]
      }




    toDocument = () => {
        this.setState({
          documentTypes: [
            { type: "Dokumendid" }
            console.log("Document was clicked");
          ]
        })
      }


      toPdf = () => {
        this.setState({
          documentTypes: [
            { type: "Pdf" }
            console.log("PDF was clicked")
          ]
        })
      }

  render(){
    return(
            <a className="a" href="/search?filter%3Atype=doc" onClick={this.toDocument}>
            <div className="icons dokument">
              <img src={dokument} alt="dokument"/>
              <a className="title">dokument</a>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a className="a" href="/search?filter%3Atype=pdf" onClick={this.toPdf}>
            <div className="icons pdf">
              <img src={pdf} alt="pdf"/>
              <a className="title">pdf</a>
            </div>
        </a>
  )
}
```

And in Results.tsx:

...

```
<DocumentType />
```

..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show a document type in `Results` component when a document in `Sidebar` component is clicked.

You have `documentType` state in `Sidebar` component and you want to pass it to `Results` component. So for that you can make `Results` component as child component of `Sidebar` component and pass the selected document type i.e `documentType` state as props.

Sidebar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Results from 'path-to-results';

class Sidebar extends Component {
  state = {
    // instead of using "documentType" as array 
    // you can make it null for initial value
    documentType: null
  }

  // instead of using "toPDF" or "toDocument" method
  // you can use single method to update the state
  handleDocType = (docType) => {
       this.setState({
          documentType: docType
       })
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         // pass "document" as argument to handleDocType method
         <a className="a" href="#" onClick={() => this.handleDocType('document')}>
           <div className="icons dokument" >
             <img src="" alt="dokument"/>
             <a className="title">dokument</a>
           </div>
        </a>
        // pass "pdf" as argument to handleDocType method
        <a className="a" href="#" onClick={() => this.handleDocType('pdf')}>
            <div className="icons pdf">
             <img src="" alt="pdf"/> 
             <a className="title">pdf</a>
           </div>
        </a>
         // checking if "documentType" is null or not
         // if it is null nothing is rendered
         // if it is not null then "Results" component is rendered
         { this.state.documentType && <Results type={this.state.documentType} /> }
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```

Results.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DocType from 'path-to-doctype'


class Results extends Component {
  // .... your other codes
  render() {
   return (
      <div>
        // ....... your other codes
       <DocType type={this.props.type} />
      </div>
   )
  }
}

export default Results
```

DocType.js

```
import React from 'react';

const DocumentType = (props ) =>{
     return(
        <div>
          <p id="fileType">{props.type}</p>
        </div>
     )
};

export default DocumentType;
```

**UPDATE**

If `Sidebar` and `DocType` components are children components of `Results` component then add `documentType` state to `Results` component and pass `documentType` state as props to `DocType` component.

Results.js

```
class Results extends Component {
  // add state "documentType"
  state = {
    documentType: null
  }

  // add "handleDocType" method
  handleDocType = (docType) => {
    this.setState({
      documentType: docType
    })
  }

  // .... your other codes

  render() {
   return (
    <div>
      // .... your other codes
      // pass "handleDocType" as props to Sidebar component
      <Sidebar handleDocType={this.handleDocType}/>
      // pass "documentType" state as props to DocType component
      <DocType type={this.state.documentType} />
    </div>
   )
  }
}

export default Results
```

Sidebar.js

```
class Sidebar extends Component {

  // use "docTypeHandler" to call parent "handleDocType" method 
  // that updates "documentType" state in Results component
  docTypeHandler = (doctype) => {
    this.props.handleDocType(doctype)
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <a className="a" href="#" onClick={() => this.docTypeHandler('document')}>
           <div className="icons dokument" >
             <img src="" alt="dokument"/>
             <a className="title">dokument</a>
           </div>
        </a>
        <a className="a" href="#" onClick={() => this.docTypeHandler('pdf')}>
            <div className="icons pdf">
             <img src="" alt="pdf"/> 
             <a className="title">pdf</a>
           </div>
        </a>

      </div>
    )

  }
}

export default Sidebar
```

DocType.js

```
const DocType = (props ) =>{
     return(
        <div>
          <p id="fileType">{props.type}</p>
        </div>
     )
};
```

Comment: If i make new 3 files, it works, but in my real project it wont. So can i export default Results into new file as <Results />?

Comment: Problem is, that i have in Results.js 200 lines of code, but i cant put that code: 

const Results = (props) => {
  return <Doctype type={props.type} />
}

in render(){ 
       return(
.....
)}

So maybe i make new component Results and put as <Results /> in line @Js Engine

Comment: no you don't need to do `const Results = (props) => { return <Doctype type={props.type} /> }` , it is  just an example on how you can use the `props` in `Result` component. I used that because in question you had just provided `<Doctype />` in `Results.tsx`

Comment: So in file, where i output all components, i just write <Doctype /> and it should work?(When i change at sidebar.js ...&& Results to Doctype @JS Engine

Comment: it will not work unless you pass props as `<Doctype type={props.type} />`  in Doctype

Comment: i have updated the answer using `Results` component as class component. You can do this in other way too eg: by making `Results` and `Sidebar` component as siblings component. Here I have made `Results` component as child component of `Sidebar` component because you wanted to pass `Sidebar` component `docType` state to `Results` component.

Comment: Ooh, so thats more like it :P, but in Results.js i will now get error: Property 'type' does not exist on type ''Readonly<{........................  @JS Engine

Comment: that's because you are using typescript and  you need to define type for `type` props

Comment: you can convert your tsx to js or add type for 'type' props in tsx. go to [this](https://charleslbryant.gitbooks.io/hello-react-and-typescript/content/Samples/ComponentPropsAndState.html)

Comment: It works, but now that onClick state value renders in my sidebar, how i get it to results.js, when sidebar.js is results.js sub-component. @Js Engine

Comment: Okey, problem is that, my sidebar has overflow:hidden; so i cant just margin or padding that content out from sidebar :D @JS Engine

Comment: can you update the question so i can know what you want

Comment: So that onClick event and state changing works. Right now, it renders the value to sidebar.js, but it should render that onClick value to results.js.(sidebar.js is results.js sub-component) @JS Engine

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly.. you wanted to show data in a div when onClick event triggers..

lets say your state object has

```
state = {
data: ''
}
```

//clicked function

```
clicked =() => {
this.setState({data: 'clickedme'})
}
```

div element: `<div onClick={this.clicked} >{this.state.data}</div>`

simple example when an `onClick` event occurs a `div` and displaying the state `data` object..

Comment: Not exactly. onClick function is in one div(in sidebar.tsx file) and if i click on it,  that state have to go to another div (result.tsx)(#filetype) In <DocumentType />.

Comment: Like having a two buttons, when i click at Button1, it should show as a text Button1. And when i click on Button2, it should show as a text Button2, in same div.